Whitelist Ip Addresses Laravel 11.3.0
I'm trying to block certain IP addresses from accessing my website using laravel 11.3.0, all the solutions i.m coming across suggest the method were you register the middleware in kernel.php but the version of laravel i'm using does not have kernel.php. So how do i go about this?
i have tried registering it in app.php
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Exceptions;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Middleware;

return Application::configure(basePath: dirname(__DIR__))
    ->withRouting(
        web: __DIR__.'/../routes/web.php',
        commands: __DIR__.'/../routes/console.php',
        health: '/up',
    )
    ->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
        $middleware->web(append: [
            \App\Http\Middleware\HandleInertiaRequests::class,
            \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\AddLinkHeadersForPreloadedAssets::class,
        ]);
        $middleware->alias([
            'role' => \Spatie\Permission\Middleware\RoleMiddleware::class,
            'permission' => \Spatie\Permission\Middleware\PermissionMiddleware::class,
            'role_or_permission' => \Spatie\Permission\Middleware\RoleOrPermissionMiddleware::class,
        ]);

         
        
        return $middleware;
    })

    ->withMiddleware([
        \App\Http\Middleware\BlockIpMiddleware::class,
    ])
    ->withExceptions(function (Exceptions $exceptions) {
        //
    })
    ->create();


ERROR
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\ApplicationBuilder::withMiddleware(): Argument #1 ($callback) must be of type ?callable, array given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\swamsite2\Swarmsite\Daniel\telegram\bootstrap\app.php on line 29 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\swamsite2\Swarmsite\Daniel\telegram\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\ApplicationBuilder.php:227
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\swamsite2\Swarmsite\Daniel\telegram\bootstrap\app.php(29): Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\ApplicationBuilder->withMiddleware(Array)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\swamsite2\Swarmsite\Daniel\telegram\artisan(12): require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...')
#2 {main}
thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\swamsite2\Swarmsite\Daniel\telegram\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\ApplicationBuilder.php on line 227

Look at the withMiddleware right above it. In fact, you can remove your withMiddleware, and move your middleware into the web() function

do you mean this one?
->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
$middleware->web(append: [
\App\Http\Middleware\HandleInertiaRequests::class,
\Illuminate\Http\Middleware\AddLinkHeadersForPreloadedAssets::class,
]);

Correct. That is probably the best place to put it.

Laravel 11 provides for the separation of the api and web middleware groups.
For my use case, what I did was something similar to this:
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Middleware;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

return Application::configure(basePath: dirname(__DIR__))
    ->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
        $middleware->web(prepend: [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\BlockIpMiddleware::class,
        ]);

        $middleware->api(append: [
            \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class . ':api',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\BlockIpMiddleware::class,
        ]);
    })->create();


